# What Are the Benefits of the Object class having a public parameterless constructor?

Tags: c#, object, abstract-class, default-constructor

I have been trying for some time to determine why the `Object` class has a public, parameterless constructor or, indeed, why it is not marked `abstract`.

I cannot see a reasonable circumstance where it would be necessary to (explicitly) call the public constructor of `Object`; we are only ever interested in the constructors of derived types.

I understand the need to provide a default constructor in `Object`, to give every other `Type` a default constructor that it can call, either implicitly or explicitly. Surely, though, this default constructor would only need to be marked as `protected`, wouldn't it?

I've seen people construct 'empty objects' in thread synchronisation; but isn't it more correct to lock a 'real object' in this scenario?

Likewise, since the functionality exposed by the `Object` class is only useful to derived types (or called statically), why isn't it an abstract class? This would seem like a better design than to have a class which gives programmers the impression that it can be meaningfully instantiated on its own.

I suspect the answer may have something to do with the inner workings of the CLR, but I would like to know why it's necessary for `Object` to have a public constructor, and if there is any reason why it couldn't be marked `abstract`.

Comment: you can't mark a constructor as abstract though perhaps you meant to mark the class abstract

Comment: @RuneFS Yes, that's what I meant. As an alternative to making the constructor protected, making the class abstract would give the same outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed probably to do with thread synchronization. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx

The fact that Microsoft uses

```
private System.Object lockThis = new System.Object();
```

In their own example tells me that in their opinion, it is perfectly correct to make a new object solely for the purpose of synchronization.

Also, Java allows the exact same thing in their synchronization examples, so Microsoft's developers might have just "followed suit" with what seemed like the standard way to have the language behave.

It is of course also possible that there is some secret technical reason in the CLR as well.

Comment: From the same MSDN article: "In practice, however, this object usually represents the resource for which thread synchronization is necessary." This suggests to me that `new object()` is mainly used in example code, rather than being recommended practice for real scenarios.

Comment: That is not the case. `private object _locker = new object()` is often recommended instead of using the object itself (or `this`), as any number of uncoordinated threads might have access to `this`, whereas use of `_locker` will more likely be intended explicitly for use as a synchronization mechanism among cooperating threads.

Comment: In light of what's been said on the topic so far, i'm happy to mark this as the accepted answer. If this single purpose is the reason why `Object` can be instantiated, it seems like a poor design decision. If there was a dedicated class to use for thread synchronisation, it sounds like `Object` could become abstract (or have its public constructor taken away).

Answer (score 0):

One reason I can think why Object should not be made abstract, and where it's default constructor is used for CLR internal functionality is when boxing and unboxing happens.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Further, thread synchronization does not have to use a 'real' object, as the purpose of using an object is to acquire the lock (once a thread acquire a lock, everyone else will have to wait till its released), not to lock the object itself.

For the sake of argument, if the thread has no interest of real objects for it's work (may be its doing some integer manipulation), then it should use an empty object created with default constructor.

Comment: When a value type gets boxed, wouldn't the CLR create an instance of a more specialised class, such as `System.Int32` or `System.DateTime`? If so, it would call the derived constructor of the relevant type.

Comment: I was referring to the 'real object' mentioned in the question, I believe there it speaks of a custom class you have defined with your own properties and methods, instead of the object provided by the framework

Comment: @BradleySmith, No, I don't think so because Int32 derives from System.ValueType, creating an instance of that will defeat the purpose of boxing, really speaking when you use int, it uses System.Int32 class.

Comment: I was under the impression that the compiler transformed variables of value types into variables of the equivalent CLR type, so an instance of the actual `ValueType` 'class' wouldn't be created until the value was boxed.

Comment: Everything in CLR inherits from system.object; there are no other variables. Int, float etc are compiler shortcuts which creates corresponding value type structs for you behind the scenes

Comment: @Raiden: A value type like `System.Int32` derives from `System.Object`, and a heap object of type `System.Int32` will behave as though it inherits `System.Object` because it does, but a storage location of `System.Int32` neither holds, nor keeps a reference to, anything that derives from `System.Object`--it holds 32 bits that represent a numeric value.  Every non-nullable value type has a corresponding heap object type which will behave as a mutable reference type (even if the value type is a struct that pretends to be immutable)